# How to get intent or some message for file modified, application closed or file closed

Tags: android-intent, android-file, android

How does one get an intent or some message for a file when modified, application when closed or file when closed? I need to perform some action after getting an alert for these operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do using [FileObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html), but its giving inconsistent results.